# More aesthetic (perhaps shallower) superscript check symbol

Tags: symbols

The standard way to produce a superscript check mark in latex would be something like

```
$\mathcal{E}^{\vee}$
```

(this is a notation often used for the dual of a locally free sheaf `$\mathcal{E}$`.) An alternative using the `amsxtra` package would be

```
$\mathcal{E}\spcheck$
```

but this looks exactly the same.  If I correctly understand, it's really just a shortcut for the former code.

Personally, I find this version of a superscript check unaesthetic.  In particular, I think it should be shallower. I could probably go searching in comprehensive symbol lists for something I like better, but I believe I'll end up with a better solution if I ask here.

**What is a good way to produce a more aesthetic (and in particular, shallower) version of a superscript check mark in math mode?**

Comment: Note: While I find useful the answers describing how to rescale the `\vee` symbol, I was kind of hoping for suggestions for better symbols altogether. In addition to shallowness, I'd like a symbol with varying thickness, and perhaps even a tiny bit of curvature.

Comment: Thanks for providing these clarifications of your objective. Could you post a hand-drawn image of the "ideal" symbol shape you have in mind? "Varying [stroke] thickness" and a "tiny bit of curvature" might indicate that you're looking for a custom-made symbol.

Comment: @Mico: If it takes a custom-made symbol, it's not worth the effort. But if I have the chance, I'll try to do as you ask. In the meantime, think loosely of a stylized "flying bird."

Comment: Another thought: perhaps what I really want is a way to write something that should really be `\check{\mathcal{E}}`, but with the check mark moved to the right on account of the size of the character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is probably heresy, but you might consider using the `\check` accent over "nothing":

[image: check accent as superscript]

the vertical position can be adjusted by inserting a zero-width `\vrule` as the "nothing":

```
\[
   \mathcal{E}\,\check{} \quad
   \mathcal{E}\,\check{\vrule height1.3ex width0pt}
\]
```

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the late answer, but I just had the very same problem. My solution is the following: use a single-guillemot character, and rotate+stretch it using `graphicx`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\chk#1{#1^{\smash{\scalebox{.7}[1.4]{\rotatebox{90}{\guilsinglleft}}}}}
```

The result is visually more elegant, as the resulting character has a varying line width.

Comment: I really like this one -- I'd suggest to use \textnormal{\guilsinglleft} to not have the command looking wired in italic environments (say, if you want to use it in a theorem environment).

Answer (score 6):

How about a macro `\smvee` (short for "small vee"), implemented in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand\smvee{\raise0.9ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\vee$}}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}^{\vee}$, $\mathcal{E}\smvee$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum*: Relative to the "ordinary" `\vee` in a superscript position, the height of the `\smvee` symbol is about 30% smaller. The amount of the vertical displacement in the macro (`0.9ex`) was chosen so that the upper endpoints of the (small) vee line up with the upper endpoint of the `\mathcal{E}` character. You may wish to adjust this to suit your personal preferences.

Answer (score 5):

The [`amssymb` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) offers `\checkmark` that has "varying thickness" and "a tiny bit of curvature":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsxtra}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand*{\dual}[1][E]{\mathcal{#1}^{\scalebox{.5}{\checkmark}}}%
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}^{\vee}$ \par
$\mathcal{E}\spcheck$ \par
$\dual$ \par
$\dual[G]$
\end{document}
```

From the above MWE, you only need [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and `amssymb`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would also like to have a symmetric mark.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust `\raisebox` and `\scalebox` arguments as needed. The extra `$` around the `\vee` look unnecessary, but they're actually required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{E}^{\vee}$

$\mathcal{E}^{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\scalebox{0.5}[0.25]{$\vee$}}}$
\end{document}
```