# How to type the check sign in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More aesthetic (perhaps shallower) superscript check symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52641/more-aesthetic-perhaps-shallower-superscript-check-symbol)

In the notation for the "dual" of something, I want to use check, like `$X^{v}$`, with the v replaced by a check. I tried `\check`, `\v`... but no one works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Are you just looking for a checkmark symbol such as `\checkmark`?

Comment: What about [More aesthetic (perhaps shallower) superscript check symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52641/5764)?

Comment: No... it looks like a v, with two sides of equal length, but it is a specific symbol, not just v.

Comment: @Werner Yes that works. I think \vee is good enough. If you think it is duplicate you can close it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options that you might be looking for:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
$\vee \bigvee \conjunction$
\end{document}
```